# Pythonで「次へ」「次のページへ」 スクレイピングしたい

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

「次へ」「次のページへ」 をPythonのselenium,beutifulsoupで　ユーザー名スクレイピングしたいです。
下記の方法で行いまたが、最初の１ページだけユーザー名スクレイピングされます。
次のページ行ってもスクレイピングするにはどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。

HTML　「次へ」ボタン

```
<button tabindex="-1" class="btn-paging next" ng-click="toPage(pageStatus.current + 1);" ng-disabled="pageStatus.current === pageStatus.last"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></button>
```

こちらの部分で全てのユーザーを取得しています。
こちらを修正する必要ありますか。

```
   time.sleep(4)
   #すべてのユーザーを取得
   users_names = [i.get_text() for i in soup.find_all(class_="fn-user ellip-1 ng-binding")]
   print(users_names)
```

全体のCode

```
# coding:utf-8
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 
#from datetime import datetime as dt, date, timedelta
import pyautogui
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt, date, timedelta

#headless background 
option = Options()
#backgrand
#option.add_argument('--headless')

#ログイン情報を維持するための設定　
# 参考→https://rabbitfoot.xyz/selenium-chrome-profile/

PROFILE_PATH ="C:\\Users\\example\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\" # 変更
option.add_argument('--user-data-dir=' + PROFILE_PATH)
option.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')

# ブラウザを開く。 #options=option background 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install() ,options=option) 

#Getting Default Adapter failed error message
option.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

strDate = dt.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")

#指定したURLに遷移 
URL= "https://example.com/apt/1/"

# Googleの検索TOP画面を開く。
driver.get(URL)

#60秒待機
time.sleep(10)

#menuボタンをクリック
menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainContainerWrapper"]/member-control/section[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/span')
menu.click()
#1秒待機
time.sleep(2)

#BeautifulSoup指定
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


#ユーザ数取得
member=soup.find(class_="member-count ng-binding").get_text()
print(member)

#ループのページ数取得
loop_num=math.ceil(int(member)/100)

print(loop_num)

for i in range(1,loop_num):
   #次のボタンクリック 
   next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainContainerWrapper"]/member-control/div/div/button[3]').click()

   time.sleep(4)
   #すべてのユーザーを取得
   users_names = [i.get_text() for i in soup.find_all(class_="fn-user ellip-1 ng-binding")]
   print(users_names)
```

もし分かる方がいましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 質問の書き方だと、貴方が関係ありそうだと考えた特定の要素の情報だけが提示されていて、サイトやWebページ全体の内容がどんな物か分かりません。それらの提示されていない情報が重要な場合も多々あるので、貴方がデータを取得したいサイトやページを明確に特定して記載した方が、助言や回答を得やすいでしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。すいません、質問修正致します。